# Test coverage for wrapper class which takes user input

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, wrapper-class

In wrapper class, there is a boolean variable named **isSelected** which I need to make **true** to increase coverage of a method. The constructor of the class always initializes the value to **false**. I am not able to change the value to **true** in test class because the list of wrapper class that is needed is returned by another method.

Check the code below and follow the comments to see the problem:

```java
public class BIContractsDetailCon {
    //Wrapper Class
    public class BIContractWrapper {
        public BI_Contracts__c biContract {get;set;}
        public Boolean isSelected {get;set;}  //The field of interest
        //constructor
        public BIContractWrapper(BI_Contracts__c biContract){
            this.biContract = biContract;
            isSelected = false;  //Constructor initializes it to false
        }
    } 

    public PageReference createRenewalOpportunity(){
    List<BIContractWrapper> biConWList = new List<BIContractWrapper>(); //List of wrapper class
    biContractWrapperlist=getBIContractWrappers(); //The function definition is pasted below
        for(BIContractWrapper w:biContractWrapperlist){
            if(w.isSelected){  //I need to make this true
                biConWlist.add(w);  //I want to cover this line
            }
        }
        //Other code
    }

    public List<BIContractWrapper> getBIContractWrappers(){
         //Other code
         for(BI_Contracts__c r: lbc){
                BIContractWrapper w = new BIContractWrapper(r);//Create wrapper class object
                biConWrapperlist.add(w);  //Add to list of wrapper class objects
        }
      return biConWrapperlist ;   //Return the list. Problem is, isSelected is always false for all objects in the list
    }
}
```

**isSelected** is not made **true** anywhere in the class. Please guide. Thank You!

### Updates:

Here is the test class that I tried. It didn't work because making **isSelected=true** is of no use as its value is overwritten in the class

```java
public static testMethod void TestBiContracts1(){

    BI_Contracts__c bicon1 = new BI_Contracts__c(Contract_Number__c='1001',Delivery_Method__c='AP Archive',Created_On__c=system.today(),
                                                    MDM_Account_ID__c='10008478',MDM_Account_Name__c='Berkeley Independent',Customer__c=account.Id,
                                                    Bill_to_MDM_ID__c='10103964',Bill_to_customer__c='2K Sports',
                                                    License_to_MDM_ID__c='10108877',License_to_Name__c='20th Century Fox',
                                                    Ship_to_MDM_ID__c='10110984',Ship_To_Name__c='12 yard Productions');

    BIContractsDetailCon.BIContractWrapper biconwrapper1 = new BIContractsDetailCon.BIContractWrapper(bicon1);

    BIContractsDetailCon biConDet = new BIContractsDetailCon();
    biConDet.biContractWrapperlist.add(biconwrapper1);

    for(BIContractsDetailCon.BIContractWrapper w: biConDet.biContractWrapperlist){
        w.isSelected=true;
    }
    biConDet.createRenewalOpportunity();
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? Can you add the test class here?

Comment: @rahulgawale I have added the test class. Thanks!

Comment: When is the `isSelected` is marked to true in your code? Does it happen from UI/VF page?

Comment: @rahulgawale Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `isSelected` true by default just for the test environment.

```
public BIContractWrapper(BI_Contracts__c biContract){
    this.biContract = biContract;
    isSelected = Test.isRunningTest();
}
```

This way isSelected will be always true in just the Test transactions and false for others.

Comment: I was looking to cover it without changing the code of the class. If there is no other option then I'll go for it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Koustubh I am not sure if there is another way around.